# « ça ... ça »: Is it confusing to use two « ça »s in close proximity to one another?

Tags: pronoms

I said to my friend:

> Quand je vous vois comme ça, s'entendre si bien l'un avec l'autre, il m’arrive de me dire que **ça** doit ressembler à **ça** d’avoir un mariage heureux. Et moi qui dis toujours que ça n'en vaut pas le coup !

I intended the first « ça » to serve as a placeholder subject for the part « d’avoir un mariage heureux » and the second one to mean "(like) that", referring to « ce que je venais de voir ».

I sometimes find myself doing this in spontaneous conversation, but I wonder if it is good style to use « ça ... ça » or « ce ... ça » like this in close proximity to one another? Does it leave some room for confusion as to what each « ça » stands for?

Comment: In the same vein as @xhaltar's answer, I think it would strain the parser a little to recognize that the first *ça* is not an expletive subject without a semantic referent (like "it" in "It looks like that") but a pronoun whose antecedent, *avoir un mariage heureux*, is forthcoming. And the misreading as expletive subject would make it an unusual or wrong place to use *ça*, I think. Hence the awkwardness. (The second *ça* is fine since its antecedent, the way the people relate, is obvious by this point.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hi. I'm not sure if this serves as a counter argument, but anyway here goes! I can easily imagine myself saying something like the following, with the « ce » and  « ça » referring to what comes before and after them respectively. What's your take on this one?

Comment: That's a more likely example, because *ce* can be an expletive subject but *ça* can't or is less usual (to my knowledge), so *ce* works better here. But note that both the pronouns have clear antecedents anyway, so it's easier to read: *ce* refers to *être...* which came before it, and *ça* refers to what immediately follows it. (Whereas in your original sentence, the first *ça* has to skip over the verb phrase to get to its antecedent, *avoir...*)

Comment: What I would definitely say is that *ce n'est pas ça* in your second sentence is a great example for the original topic of the question: since *ça n'est pas ça* would technically be valid because each *ça* has a real antecedent, which one is more natural? And I think we would probably all agree that *ce n'est pas ça* rolls of the tongue more easily. :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Indeed, I wouldn't dream of saying « **ça** n'est pas **ça** ». As to my 1st sentence: Is it just me, but « **cela** doit ressembler à **ça** » doesn't  quite sit right with me, and much less so with « **ce** doit ressembler à **ça** ».

Comment: *cela* would have the same problem as *ça*, but *ce* might be okay. That said, untangling the flipped pronouns/antecedents then becomes the more important problem, and I think @xhaltar's second option does a good job of that (notice how it has *ce* in *c'est*, but it's an expletive pronoun without an antecedent, since the verb isn't an infinitive --
 thus the only pronoun with an antecedent in the sentence is *ça*, whose antecedent is before it). Interestingly, though, xhaltar's first option does have the flipping but sounds okay... This is probably the end of my useful commentary for now...

Comment: What about three? “Ça, ça donne ça” sounds perfectly normal to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a mistake, however, this would maybe seem a little strange to some people.
Using two `ça` is not an incorrect way of saying things.

You could also say :

`[...] il m'arrive de me dire que c'est cela, avoir un mariage heureux [...]`

`[...] il m'arrive de me dire que c'est à ça que ressemble un mariage heureux [...]`